# Why my virtualized list does not re-render when the data passed as prop actualizes?

Tags: react-native, render, react-virtualized

I am having a problem that I can't solve by my own. I am making an app for making lists in React Native, and in my main screen, that shows the session initiated by the user, I have to render all the lists that he had saved previously. Here is the code of my session component.

```
export default function Session({navigation,route}){
    const {user} = useContext(myContext)
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false)
    const [lists, setLists] = useState(route.params.lists)
    let keyListCounter = 0

    const handleButton = async () => {
        await AsyncStorage.removeItem("token")
        navigation.navigate("Login")
    }

    const updateList = (title,newElement) => {
        axios.put(`http://${REACT_APP_BACK_URI}/api/lists/add-list-element`, {nickname: user,title,element: newElement})
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status == 200) {
                    setLists(res.data.userLists)
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        navigation.setOptions({
            title: user,
            headerTitleAlign: "left",
            headerRight: () => (
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => handleButton()}>
                    <Text style={styles.logoutText}>Logout</Text>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            )
        })
    },[navigation,user])

    return (
        <View style={styles.mainContainerView}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.mainContainerScrollView}>
                <View style={styles.textListContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.listsText}>LISTAS ACTIVAS: </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.numberListsText}>{lists.length}</Text>
                </View>
                {lists.map(elem => <List key={keyListCounter++} list={elem} updateList={updateList}/>)}
            </ScrollView>

            <Pressable style={styles.newListPressable} onPressIn={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
                <Text style={styles.newListText}>+</Text>
            </Pressable>
            <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                <Modal
                    visible={modalVisible}
                    animationType="slide"
                    transparent={true}
                >
                    <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                        <View style={styles.modalView}>
                            <Text>MODAL</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Modal>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

My question is why after I actualize the state of "lists", whose elements are passed as props to the List component, the virtualized list that I have in the List component does not re-renderizes automaticaly.

Here I show also the code of the List component.

```
export default function List({list,updateList}){
    const {elements, title} = list
    let elementId = 0
    const virtualizedList = useRef()
    const [showVirtualizedList, setShowVirtualizedList] = useState("none")
    const [showDownArrow, setShowDownArrow] = useState(true)
    const [showUpArrow, setShowUpArrow] = useState(false)
    let [newElementArray, setNewElementArray] = useState([])
    let [listElements, setListElements] = useState(elements)

    const getItem = (item) => ({
        id: elementId++,
        title: item
    });

    //List Pressable Events
    const handlePressIn = () => {
        if (showVirtualizedList == "none") setShowVirtualizedList("flex")
        else setShowVirtualizedList("none")

        setShowDownArrow(!showDownArrow)
        setShowUpArrow(!showUpArrow)
    }

    //New element Pressable Events
    const handleNewElement = () => {
        setNewElementArray([...newElementArray,uuid.v4()])
    }

    //NewListItem TouchableWithoutFeedback Events
    const deleteElementInput = newItemID => {
        const elementsArray = newElementArray.filter(elem => elem != newItemID)
        setNewElementArray(elementsArray)
    }

    const addListElement = (newElement,newItemID) => {
        updateList(title,newElement)
        deleteElementInput(newItemID)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        virtualizedList.current.setNativeProps({display: showVirtualizedList})
        LogBox.ignoreLogs(['VirtualizedLists should never be nested']);
    },[showVirtualizedList, virtualizedList])

    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <Pressable 
                style={styles.listElement}
                onPressIn={() => handlePressIn()}
            >
                <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.listElementText}>{title} </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.listElementQuantity}>({listElements.length})</Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <DownArrow show={showDownArrow}/>
                    <UpArrow show={showUpArrow}/>
                </View>
            </Pressable>

            <View>
                <VirtualizedList
                    data={listElements}
                    initialNumToRender={10}
                    getItemCount={() => listElements.length}
                    renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem item={item}/>}
                    getItem={() => getItem(listElements[elementId])}
                    ref={virtualizedList}
                />
            </View>

            {newElementArray.length > 0 ? newElementArray.map(elem => {
                return (
                    <NewListItem 
                        key={elem} 
                        id={elem}
                        newElementArray={newElementArray}
                        deleteElementInput={deleteElementInput}
                        addListElement={addListElement}
                    />
                )
                }) : ""
            }

            <Pressable style={styles.newElementPressable} onPressIn={() => handleNewElement()}>
                <Text style={styles.newElementText}>+</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I solve the problem using a FlatList instead of a VirtualizedList. For some reason the FlatList re-renders when the Item is updated and the VirtualizedList no. I don't know why.....